# Dialog close event not firing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

This is not working like I expect it:

```
$("#generalContactWindow").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    draggable: true,
    width: 600, height: 'auto',
    closeOnEscape: true,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    close: function(event, ui) {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'DetailsGeneralForm', 'HideForm', document.location.href]); 
        console.log('_trackEvent DetailsGeneralForm HideForm called');
    }
});
```

The part with `_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'DetailsGeneralForm', 'HideForm', document.location.href]);` will never happen if I click on the close button or press escape key.

The close link looks like this:

```
<a class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close" href="#" unselectable="on" style="-moz-user-select: none;"><span unselectable="on" style="-moz-user-select: none;">X</span></a>
```

I think this is the standard.

Reason for all this is that I need to track the opening and the closing of the dialog.
I can track the opening quite well, but just not the closing. What should I do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your console.log() working? Have you got any errors?

Comment: no, the consoloe.log is not working

Comment: no, the console.log() is not working.

Answer (score 1):

you'll need to setup the click event for your close button

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Cy2B6/)

using jQuery [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegation this will make your close button call the jquery UI dialog `close` event

```
$("#generalContactWindow").on('click', '.ui-dialog-titlebar-close', function() {
    $("#generalContactWindow").dialog('close');
});​
```

Comment: Thanks so much but in my case it's not working because the ui-dialog-close it outside the #generalContactWindow div. I saw your jsfiddle and used instead .ui-dialog-titlebar and ui-dialog-container but with non of them can I get the close event to fire up.